# PHP Mailer - Additional Fields

Tags: php, phpmailer

I have searched and researched high and low and I am still unable to find an answer.

I am using PHP Mailer that came with a theme we purchased (version 5.2.1). I am trying to figure out how to capture the phone number and send it along with the other data in the email that is sent.

The Form:

```
<form method="post" action="#" id="contactForm">
                <div class="input-prepend" style="margin-left:0px;margin-right:0px">
                    <input class="input-xlarge required" id="name" type="text" placeholder="Name (Required)" />
                </div>
                <div class="input-prepend" style="margin-left:0px">
                    <input class="input-xlarge required" id="email" type="text" placeholder="Email (Required)" />
                </div>
                <div class="input-prepend" style="margin-left:0px">
                    <input class="input-xlarge required" id="phone" name="phone" type="text" placeholder="Phone (Required)" />
                </div>
                <div class="input-prepend" style="margin-left:0px">
                    <input class="input-xlarge required" id="subject" type="text" placeholder="Subject (Required)" />
                </div>
                <div class="input-prepend" style="margin-left:0px">
                    <input class="input-xlarge required" id="children-3-7" type="text" placeholder="Number of Children (Age 3 - 7) (Required)" />
                </div>
                <div class="input-prepend" style="margin-left:0px">
                    <input class="input-xlarge required" id="children-7-14" type="text" placeholder="Number of Children (Age 7 - 14) (Required)" />
                </div>
                <div class="input-prepend" style="margin-left:0px">
                    <input class="input-xlarge required" id="adults" type="text" placeholder="Number of Adults (Required)" />
                </div>
                <div class="input-prepend" style="margin-left:0px">
                    <textarea name="message-input" id="message" class="span12 required" cols="5" rows="5" placeholder="Message (Required)" style="margin-left:0px"></textarea>
                </div>

                <div class="clearfix" style="margin:10px 0px 0px 0px">
                    <a href="#" class="ignore btn resetButton"><span>Reset Form</span></a>
                    <a href="#" class="ignore btn submitButton"><span>Send Message</span></a>

                    <!-- Processing data trick -->
                    <div id="loadingForm">
                        <img src="images/normal/ajax-small.gif" alt="ajax-small" />
                    </div>
                    <!-- Processing data trick -->
                </div>

                <br />
                <div class="clearfix">
                <!-- contact notice -->
                <div class="alert alert-block fade" id="contact-notice">
                    <span><strong>Warning!</strong> All fields above are required to send the message properly.</span>
                </div>
                <!-- contact notice -->
            </div>
            </form>
```

The PHP

```
<?php

require_once("class.phpmailer.php");

send();

function send(){

 $mailer = new PHPMailer();
 $mailer->IsSMTP();
 $mailer->Host = 'host.com';
 $mailer->SMTPAuth = true;
 $mailer->SMTPSecure = "tls";
 $mailer->Port = 587;
 $mailer->CharSet="utf-8";
 $mailer->IsHTML(true);

 $mailer->Username = 'mail-bot@mail.com';
 $mailer->Password = 'PASSWORD';
 $mailer->FromName = $_POST['name'];
 $mailer->From = $_POST['email'];
 $mailer->AddAddress('ADDRESS','NB=AME');
 $mailer->Subject = $_POST['subject'];
 $mailer->MsgHTML = $_POST['message'];

 $phone = $_POST['phone'];
 /**$mailer->Age1 = $_POST['children-3-7'];
 //$mailer->Age2 = $_POST['children-7-14'];
 //$mailer->Age3 = $_POST['adults'];**/

 $mailer->Body = "From : ".$_POST['name']."<br /> E-mail : ".$_POST['email']."<br /> Subject : ".$_POST['subject']."<br />Message : ".$_POST['message']."<br />Phone : $phone";

 if(!$mailer->Send()){

 echo "error^Message could not be sent.<br />";
 echo "Mailer Error: " . $mailer->ErrorInfo;
 exit;

 }
 else{

 echo "ok^Message sent successfully!";

 }

 }

?>
```

As you can see I am attempting to use

```
$phone = $_POST['phone'];
```

to extract the phone number and then adding it to the message body by using

```
$mailer->Body = "From : ".$_POST['name']."<br /> E-mail : ".$_POST['email']."<br /> Subject : ".$_POST['subject']."<br />Message : ".$_POST['message']."<br />Phone : $phone";
```

To inject the phone number

I have also tried injecting in the following way

```
$mailer->Body = "From : ".$_POST['name']."<br /> E-mail : ".$_POST['email']."<br /> Subject : ".$_POST['subject']."<br />Message : ".$_POST['message']."<br />Phone: ".$_POST['phone'];
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: are you recieving email ?

Comment: Thankyou.Yes, mail is received fine. Email, Subject and Message are injecting into the email fine as well.

Comment: so can you show me PHP mailer class to make sure that is there any variable of phone number there ?

Comment: Sure. It is 2500+ lines so I wont paste it here, but it is the same one as you can find via this link https://github.com/cbschuld/pegasusphp.org/tree/master/includes/phpmailer-5.2.1

Comment: Ok and where is your form submitting code ? can you directly call `send()` function after submit ?

Comment: Not sure if I understand your question - the form on the contact page is submitting the data to the php form handler (code above) and has an include of the mailer class I sent above.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/71316/discussion-between-afaan-and-icedquick).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears as if there was a secondary validation sitting in our main .js file that was validating empty fields before posting them via ajax. Phone number needed to be added in there before it posted it and I can now successfully capture the data.

Thanks for your help!